# Tableview cell content is changed when cell goes off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two kinds of tableview cells , say Paid and unpaid.I have check boxes on left , to unpaid cells.
When tableview is first time loaded , all cells are in correct format.
but when i scroll up , as the cells go off screen and come bak screen , their content is changed.showing the images.[image]

and after scrolling up and down i get this.

[image]

it is really frustrating. i have searched over SO , but of no avail.

My code is below :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    data1 = [[responseDict valueForKey:@"cases"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    data1 = [data1 valueForKey:@"procedures"];
    data1 = [data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[[[valueForKey:@"paid"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"procedures"];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        //if ([payemtStr  isEqual:@"0"]) {
        //UnpiadCell



        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // Configure the cell...
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }


    UIButton * checkBtn= (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    UILabel *payToLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UIButton * expandBtn= (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:106];

    if ([[data1 valueForKey:@"paid"]boolValue] ==1) {
        payToLbl.text = @"";
        [checkBtn setHidden:YES];
        [expandBtn setHidden:YES];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else {
    payToLbl.text = @"Pay to";
        [checkBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [expandBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(collapseExpandButtonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        if([[[selectedCellsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
            [checkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        else
            [checkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // [[expandCellsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Expand"]
        if([[[expandCellsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] isEqualToString:@"Expand"])
            [expandBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"collapse.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        else
            [expandBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"expand.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//        if ([selectedCellsArray containsObject:@"Check"]) {
//            self.payBtn.hidden = NO;
//        }
//        else {
//            self.payBtn.hidden = YES;
//        }

    }


    UILabel *mainTitleLbk = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    mainTitleLbk.textColor= [UIColor blackColor];
    mainTitleLbk.text = [data1 valueForKey:@"provider"];
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103]).text = [data1 valueForKey:@"description"];
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:104]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",
                                                [data1 valueForKey:@"line_1"],
                                                [data1 valueForKey:@"line_2"]
                                                ];
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:109]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [data1 valueForKey:@"city"],[data1 valueForKey:@"state"]];

    // [data1 valueForKey:@"zip"]
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@" ,[data1 valueForKey:@"zip"],[data1 valueForKey:@"phone"]];
    // handeling check uncheck buttons
    return cell;


}
```

Comment: Cells are reused so you need to make sure you set all attributes in your if and else clauses. For example you set items to hidden in the if but don't set them to not hidden in the else. Also you are adding the button target each time; when cells are reused you will end up with the action added multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewCell is reused everytime a new row appear. So after scrolling up and down, the first row is not the newly created UITableviewCell. Adding 2 line of code may fix the problem:

```
{
payToLbl.text = @"Pay to";
[checkBtn setHidden:NO];
[expandBtn setHidden:NO];
.......
```

Please also clear these button actions.